# Can you safely synchronize on a Java method parameter?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, locking, synchronized

Take this code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Object _lock = new Object();
    private final MyMutableClass _mutableObject = new MyMutableClass()

    public void myMethod() {
        synchronized(_lock) { // we are synchronizing on instance variable _lock
            // do something with mutableVar 
            //(i.e. call a "set" method on _mutableObject)
        }
    }
}
```

now, imagine delegating the code inside myMethod() to some helper class where you pass the lock

```
public class HelperClass {
    public helperMethod(Object lockVar, MyMutableClass mutableVar) {
        synchronized(lockVar) { // we are now synchronizing on a method param, 
                                // each thread has own copy
            // do something with mutableVar 
            // (i.e. call a "set" method on mutableVar)
        }
    }
}
```

can "myMethod" be re-written to use the HelperClass by passing its lock var, so that everything is still thread safe?  i.e.,

```
public void myMethod() {
    _helperObject.helperMethod(_lock, _mutableObject);
}
```

I am not sure about this, because Java will pass the lockVar by value, and every thread will get a separate copy of lockVar (even though each copy points to the same object on the heap).  I guess the question comes down to how 'synchronized' keyword works -- does it lock on the variable, or the value on the heap that the variable references?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Synchronization is done upon *objects*, not *variables*.**

Variables/members [sometimes] contain *objects* and it is the resulting *object* contained in [variable] `x` that is actually synchronized upon in `synchronized(x)`.

There are a few other issues with thread-visibility of variables (e.g. might read a "stale" object from a variable), but that does not apply here: there is no re-assignment of `_lock` and the visibility of the initial ("final") assignment is guaranteed. Because of this it is guaranteed that, in this case, the method parameter will always contain the correct (same) *object* used for the synchronization.

If the lock object used (where presumably `_lock` is not final) changes, however, then that would require re-evaluation of the appropriate values/thread-visibility but otherwise does not differ from any cross-thread access.

Happy coding.

Comment: Actually, my example wasn't really correct.  I didn't mean to mark _mutableObject as final.  I don't think this locking will work *IF* _mutableObject in the parent object is non-final.  If you pass that value as a variable into the helper method, and then you change _mutableObject to point to something else in the parent class, when the helper method runs it is no longer holding onto the correct reference for _mutableObject.  The lock will still lock, but you will be "protecting" a stale value of _mutableObject.  That is really what my question was supposed to point out.

Comment: I will accept your answer assuming that this will only work if _mutableObject is 'final' in the parent class.  The _lock object always needs to be declared final, no matter which version of my example you use.  In fact, I shouldn't have created my example to include a "mutable" object.  I should have just described that I wanted to protected a non-final variable, call it "private Object _object".  I want the lock to protect that value changing.  If the example is changed to that, I don't think you can pass the locking off to a helper method, because helper method gets stale _object reference.

Comment: @Android Dev An object used for a lock *object* should be stable and unique for each mutually exclusive synchronization desired. The variable (or object) being protected by the synchronization can change (the synchronization context will ensure the memory barriers and happens-before guarantees as long as all such synchronizations operate upon the same lock *object*). It's generally a bad idea to swap an object used for a lock (the lock *object* can be mutated and this will not affect it's usage with `synchronized` -- the importance is that the *same object* is used for synchronization.)

Comment: I am not swapping the object used for the lock.  I am swapping the object that I'm protecting WITH the lock.  I understand what you are saying about the synchronization happening on the lock _object_ (not variable).  However, if I am trying to protect an instance variable by using the lock, I don't think I can write a helper method and pass that variable in (with the lock, which I can pass in), because as soon as I pass the variable in as an argument, it can be changed by another thread.  I need to synchronize on the lock before passing into helper method.  That's how I need to solve this.